# How to display the number “12” in the format of “0000012”

Tags: c#

How to display the number “12” in the format of “0000012” Using C#

Comment: Keep in mind that some readers and many programs will interpret a leading 0 as an octal value: `echo $((012+0)) 
10`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
var str = string.Format("{0:d7}", 12);
```

Answer (score 9):

```
var formatted = String.Format("{0:0000000}", 12);
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:0000000}", 12);
```

I will add that if "12" is a `string` (it's in double quotes)

```
var formatted = "12".PadLeft(7, '0');
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var a = 12;
var b = a.ToString("D7");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = 12;
string b = a.ToString("0000000");
```