# Format the number 11 as 00000011

Tags: c#, .net, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to display the number “12” in the format of “0000012”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076177/how-to-display-the-number-12-in-the-format-of-0000012)

I am trying to get a number to format itself within a predefined amount of 000's (sorry if I am not clear, its not easy to describe)

```
e.g. 112 would become 00000112

and e.g. 1 would become 00000001
```

Answer (score 11):

Try it like this `myNumber.ToString("D8");`

Comment: I agree - unless `myNumber` is actually the string representation of a number, in which case `PadLeft(8, '0')` would have to be used.  I only say this because there's a bit of confusion as to whether the value is coming in as a numeric type or not (there's no code in the question)

Comment: I guess you beat me to it, +1

Answer (score 2):

```
int i = 12;
var text = i.ToString("00000");
//text will be "00012"
```

Answer (score 2):

for say, leading zeros up to 8 chars do

```
string.Format("{0:D8}", value);
```

or

```
value.ToString("D8");
```

Its [explained here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
int number = 11;
string padded = number.ToString().PadLeft(8, '0');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int foo = 11;
foo.ToString("D8");
```

--> 00000011

Answer (score 0):

You can either look at the length and use the `String.PadLeft()` function, or you can add enough 0s to the front of the number (whatever it's length) and then use the `String.Right()` function to take as many characters as you need.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
int number = 11;
string text = number.ToString("00000000");
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use String.PadLeft method which aligns string on the right.
If the length is less than one of the number you give PadLeft would not change the value.

```
public string ZeroFill(int number, int length)
    return number.ToString().PadLeft(length, '0');
}
```